# Upgrading .NET Framework to 4.7.2 on IIS Server changes how website displays on IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

After updating our IIS server's .Net Framework from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2, we now have a semi-broken website, but only on IE, and only when viewing the site on a remote server. CSS seems to be broken; menus, buttons, etc. The really odd thing is that it looks right on chrome and Firefox, and even more confusing, it looks right when browsing the site locally on the IIS server. It is only broken when viewing the site remotely using IE. So that tells me that the server is sending everything just fine, scripts, css, html, etc; but that I don't know why IE 11 fails to render it right. It did before updating the framework. Anyone else experience this and knows what may be going on?

Comment: This is a long shot, but are any of the mime types missing on the new IIS version?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - I looked for js and css, which are the only types that matter for this case, and they are not missing, but if they were, I would expect that all browsers would fail to render correctly, not just IE.

Comment: 'Stupid' question, I know, but have you cleared the browser's cache?

Comment: Have you checked mime types for all the fonts?

Comment: @PoulBak - yes, as did my coworker; he can duplicate the issue exactly, meaning, works on Chrome and FireFow but not IE 11.

Comment: @IrishChieftain - no, but why would changes in fonts affect css?

Comment: Happened me recently... was missing a font type and got all types of weird behavior and seemingly unrelated errors.

Comment: Try toggling compatibility mode in IE when browsing remotely?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - tried it; didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Are other sites on same server working?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - no other sites on this box, it's our QA box for just this 1 app.

Comment: I'd definitely deploy another site there to narrow it down. Then you'll know if it's the server or the site ;-)

Comment: When viewing the site remotely using IE, have you tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether the CSS file load success, and it don't contain JavaScript error?